# Weird Leg Problem

Tags: armature, weight-painting

For some reason the legs of my model act weird whenever I move the hips or root bone downwards. My character's legs cross over each other as though he needs to the loo lol. I don't understand what's happened as everything is pretty much the same when I started the Weight Painting; nothing seems out of place.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bend the knees a bit, in *Edit* mode, so that Blender understands how they are supposed to bend. Also, I think you should parent the feet and hands controllers to your roots so that it also follows, but that's another topic...

[image]

Comment: And as simple as that... Thank you. :D
What, is that for every controller bone to the root bone?

Comment: You need one bone to control your whole armature, it looks like in your case, "C_root" is supposed to be the root bone